# Creating a subroutine to tell a player when the coordinates that they have entered are already occupied

Tags: python, subroutine

Ive created a list containing all the coordinates that are available and so my idea is that once a coordinate has been entered it is removed of the list and placed into another list called Taken_Coord.

But I just know my code can be a lot more efficient than what it is I just not sure how, if more info is needed just let me know
Here is the Code:

```
Board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

Coordinate = 0
YCoordinate = 0
ValidMove = False
CurrentSymbol = ''
StartSymbol = ''
PlayerOneSymbol = ''
PlayerTwoSymbol = ''
Answer = ''
Aval_coordinate = ['11','12','13','21','22','23','33','32''31']
Taken_Coord = 0

def CheckValidMove(XCoordinate, YCoordinate, Board, Taken_Coord, Aval_coordinate):
ValidMove = True
Taken_Coord = (''+str(XCoordinate) + str(YCoordinate) + '')
count = Aval_coordinate.count(Taken_Coord)
if (XCoordinate < 1) or (XCoordinate > 3):
    ValidMove = False
if(YCoordinate < 1) or (YCoordinate > 3):
    ValidMove = False
elif count == 0:
    ValidMove = False
elif Taken_Coord == '11':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('11')
elif Taken_Coord == '12':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('12')
elif Taken_Coord == '13':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('13')
elif Taken_Coord == '21':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('21')
elif Taken_Coord == '22':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('22')
elif Taken_Coord == '23':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('23')
elif Taken_Coord == '33':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('33')
elif Taken_Coord == '31':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('31')
elif Taken_Coord == '32':
    Aval_coordinate.pop('32')
return ValidMove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah something like is. Also don't use uppercase names for varibales or functions, they're used for classes. Also the `list.pop()` method needs the index you want to remove, not the string. Want you probably want to use is `remove()`

```
def check_valid_move(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, board, taken_coord, aval_coordinate):
    taken_coord = f"{x_coordinate}{y_coordinate}"
    if x_coordinate and y_coordinate not in range(1,4):
        return False
    if taken_coord not in aval_coordinate:
        return False
    aval_coordinate.remove(taken_coord)
    return True
```

Comment: That's great honestly I knew there was some way of shortening it! Thank you

Comment: if your're happy with it, mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Also i added a small part to get rid of the not so nice "count"